# Will we leak the android service connection if the client's process is killed by android?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-service, activity-lifecycle

**Condition:**
I have a client activity "X" of a remote service (with AIDL) that calls the `bindService()` in the `onCreate()` and `unbindService()` in the `onDestroy()`. Assume that this activity has been started but not in the foreground (`onStop()` has happened).

It is said that when android system needs more memory elsewhere it might kill the process of another activity with less priority (possibly "X").

If, says, the android system decides to kill "X"'s process, according to the activity-lifecycle diagram the `onDestroy()` will not be called if the process is killed when more memory is needed.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

**Question:**
Will this cause it to leak the service connection? Is it safer then to bind and unbind service in `onStart()` and `onStop()`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: Will this cause it to leak the service connection?

The `ServiceConnection` object would be in the process of "X" and therefore will go away when that process is terminated.

Comment: Oh, ok... But when a client binds to a remote service does it only involve the resources in the client's process? I mean the android system itself doesn't keep any resources involving the binding (that will be released upon call to unbindService()?

Comment: @Surya Wijaya Madjid: There is probably something. However, it's the OS's job to clean that up, and even if it does wind up leaking, it is unlikely to be significant heap space. I wouldn't worry about it unless MAT is showing signs of significant leaks in your service process.

Comment: Hmm.. OK. So as a conclusion I'd say that doing bindService() in the onCreate() and unbindService() in the onDestroy() still remains as a good alternative then. Thanks for the answer :)