# Can a Service be killed but the Process kept alive

Tags: android, service, process

Say my app has an Activity that the user is interacting with.
My Application process priority is now 1 - highest.

Say I also have a background started service in my application. (that is not bound)

In extreme memory pressure, (assume all lower priority processes has been killed) can the O.S kill my service (meaning to remove its reference to the service and call its onDestroy method) but still keep my application process alive?

I have read the official documentation,
Also, Dianne's response to this thread:
[Android service killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041971/android-service-killed)
And also this thread:
[When Service is killed, can the process be still alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087596/when-service-is-killed-can-the-process-be-still-alive)

However, I want to be 100% sure that this is not an option, not 99%.

Is there an official documentation that the O.S in this situation will kill the entire process?

Thanks

Comment: For being 100% sure you can take AOSP source code and find the answer.

Comment: What you said could be an answer for each question asked.
Why should anyone ask a question if they can simply read they entire android O.S and find it?

Comment: So why not do it before asking? I can ensure you that this works and you can post your own answer to your question and even accept it, thus bringing benefit to SO community.

Comment: Because no need to do it before asking if its knowledge that isn't common but that some1 else already investigated, read CommonsWare. Anyways not relevant anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In extreme memory pressure, (assume all lower priority processes has been killed) can the O.S kill my service (meaning to remove its reference to the service and call its onDestroy method) but still keep my application process alive?

First, you only have one process by default.

Second, if that process is the foreground UI ("my app has an Activity that the user is interacting with"), it is not going to be terminated due to low memory conditions. Only background processes are subject to termination.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I appriciate you taking the time to respond, I read many of your posts.

Regarding:
"First, you only have one process by default."
Yes, I know that, when I wrote "Assume all lower priority processes has been killed" - meaning other low priority application processes (not my app process) so now the app will have to destroy foreground processes.

Regarding your second comment, "Only background processes are subject to termination"
It is not true. in extreme situations, they can: create two apps that use JNI to consume increasing RAM memory. eventually one of them will terminate.

Comment: @ZiviMagic: "create two apps that use JNI to consume increasing RAM memory. eventually one of them will terminate" -- only one is in the foreground. "can the O.S kill my service (meaning to remove its reference to the service and call its onDestroy method) but still keep my application process alive?" -- the OS does not "kill" a service, or any other component, due to low memory conditions. Android terminates background processes due to low memory conditions.

Comment: You can start a foreground service in both of them so both of their processes would have foreground priority. I tried it, you can see that one of them will get killed eventually even though it has foreground priority.

But anyways from your answer, I take it that android terminates processes and not specific services in the process due to lack of memory.

Thanks

Comment: @ZiviMagic: "You can start a foreground service in both of them so both of their processes would have foreground priority" -- AFAIK, despite the name, that's still a lower importance than is the actual foreground UI. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html and `IMPORTANCE_PERCEPTIBLE` versus `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`.

Comment: This is very insightful!!! haven't seen that before. thanks :) 
From what I read in the official Android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

They should be the same, But I guess even within the each priority category there are some inner categories.
Have you any idea how these different categories relate to the official documentation, is there a clear list that lists the priorities?

Comment: @ZiviMagic: AFAIK, the official roster is those `IMPORTANCE_` constants on `ActivityManager`. It's possible there are hidden or otherwise undocumented ones, but I am not aware of any.

Comment: @CommonsWare Would the service's "onDestroy" method be called before killing its process (due to high usage of RAM by other apps)? Or would the process be killed just like that? Also, would the intent that has started it before - will restart the service later (sticky behavior) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Or would the process be killed just like that?" -- that depends. In the case of low-memory conditions, there's an element of importance not only of the running processes, but the process that needs to be running. An incoming phone call, for example, cannot wait for a bunch of `onDestroy()` invocations. In cases like this, the OS reserves the right to terminate processes immediately. Also bear in mind that if the user force-stops your app, `onDestroy()` is also not going to be called. With regards to restarts, anything other than force-stop should trigger a restart.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see. So even when the service is a foreground service, its process could be killed by the OS because some other app (like a heavy game) uses a lot of RAM , and you won't always even get the chance to notice it via onDestroy.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Correct. The odds are fairly low, but they are not zero.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. As always, you are very resourceful . Here, take my +1 :)

Comment: this is a great explanation to what you rightly wrote: https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f#.qm5mv9w4v